# Azure Python VM scale set network profile has no network interface configurations

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to deploy VM Scale Set via the Azure python SDK.
When I'm trying to create the scale set an exception is thrown:
`Message: VM scale set network profile /subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/MatrixRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/ScaleSetName/updateGroups/63e63aa7-0f01-42be-88fd-ada85c591967 has no network interface configurations`

I'm creating the VM scale set via this code snippet:

```
region_name = 'eastus'
        sku = Sku(name='Standard_DS1_v2', capacity=5)

        vmss_profile = VirtualMachineScaleSetVMProfile(storage_profile={
                    'image_reference':
                    {
                        'id': '/subscriptions/e500fb85-1759-463b-b828-0d4e0b38a305/resourceGroups/MatrixRG/'
                              'providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/libscapiImageEastUS'
                    }
                },
            os_profile={
                'adminUsername': 'ubuntu',
                'computerName': 'myVM',
                'linux_configuration': {
                    'disable_password_authentication': True,
                    'ssh': {
                        'public_keys': [{
                            'path': '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys',
                            'key_data': key_data
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            network_profile={
            'network_interfaces': [{
                'id': nic
            }]
        })
        vmss = VirtualMachineScaleSet(region_name, sku=sku, virtual_machine_profile=vmss_profile,
                                      upgrade_policy=upgrade_policy, single_placement_group=True)
        response = self.compute_client.virtual_machine_scale_sets.create_or_update(self.resource_group, 'HyperMPC',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the Azure VM Scale Set, the NIC should be an object of [VirtualMachineScaleSetVMProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_10_01.models.virtualmachinescalesetvmprofile?view=azure-python). And the [VirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_10_01.models.virtualmachinescalesetnetworkprofile?view=azure-python) must contains a list of the NIC configurations. The NIC number dependant on your VM Scale Set capacity.

Then all the Azure VM Scale Set functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_10_01.operations.virtualmachinescalesetsoperations?view=azure-python). Hope this will help you. Any more question please give me the message.